# Embedding Python with basic IDE

Tags: python, debugging, mfc, ide, embedding

My company has a C/C++ application developed using Visual Studio. Currently we have a Visual Basic plugin which lets you open a built-in text editor and run VB code. This built-in text editor gives the user all the basic debugging tools (break, watch, step...). I was wondering how could I do that using Python. The tricky part is that the python interpreter has to be launched from inside the main application, so that they have access to the same memory space.

I already have a swig interface for the application API and did a proof of concept VB script in which I loaded Python as a DLL and executed a script as described [here](http://docs.python.org/c-api/veryhigh.html). This works perfectly when I am sure the script has no bugs, but it would be much easier if I could have some sort of interface which I can debug the script being executed.

I had a look into the pdb module, but it dosent look like the way to go. If someone could just point me into the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had some luck embedding Spyder in a C/C++ program that I had created wrappers for (using PySide). Since the wrappers included the main application logic, I turned the program into a python application and then embedded Spyder using one of their examples.

However, it uses pdb or winpdb under the hood, so complete functionality is still not there IMHO.

Comment: Any chance you could share some code with me? I sent a e-mail to the Spyder list, but wasn't that lucky.

Comment: Sorry, didn't your question. In the months since your question, I've come to the conclusion that embedding anything more than the spyder InternalShell doesn't work like you and I would like (being able to access the same memory space). For what it is worth, my code is based on their example here: http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/source/browse/app_example/example.pyw

Comment: Yeah i have been playing with it. Thanks for revisiting this anyway. If you ever come to a solution you wanna share shoot me a msg.